# Magento 2 custom theme is not deployed

Tags: deployment, command-line, themes, file-permissions, magento2

I have created a custom theme for Magento 2 production version. I have selected my theme from the back-end. But it renders only HTML. I deployed the static content but my theme is not in the

```
pub\static\frontend\Magento
```

directory so I get 404 for `.css` and `.js` files. I have tried setting file permissions but no luck. In the command line window after deploying luma theme it continues to deploy admin. Any help is appreciated.

file structure:

```
app/design/frontend/Muaw/mytheme:

|-etc
|   |-view.xml
|-media
|   |-preview.png
|-registration.php
|-theme.xml
|-composer.json
|-web
|   |-css
|   |-js
|   |-fonts
|   |-images
|-Magento_Theme
|   |-layout
|   |   |-default.xml
```

Files:

theme.xml:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>My Theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
<parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
</media>
```

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "magento/theme-frontend-luma",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
},
"type": "magento2-theme",
"version": "100.0.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
}
}
```

registration.php:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
        'frontend/Muaw/mytheme',
        __DIR__
    );
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your `media/preview.jpg` and change **name** in your composer.json file to `Muaw/mytheme`.